# Could you please provide an example of Powershell script adding NAPTR record to DNS?

Tags: powershell, dns, windows-server, domain-name

Using this manual https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649925.aspx I wrote next script:

```
Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -Service test -ZoneName ms_dns -InternetAddress 10.161.35.15 -InternetProtocol TCP -Wks $false
```

But get an error: *Add-DnsServerResourceRecord : Failed to create resource record False in zone ms_dns on server MS_DNS_MASTER.*

As I understood , the parameter -Wks must be a boolean.

Comment: What happens if you leave it out altogether?

Comment: It will require to enter -Wks parameter.

Comment: What about if you set it to `$null` in that case?

Comment: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Wks'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Managem
ent.Automation.SwitchParameter". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or
 0.

Comment: try `-Wks:$false` instead of `-Wks $false`

Comment: It gives an error: 
Add-DnsServerResourceRecord : Failed to create resource record test in zone ms_dns on server MS_DNS_MASTER.
...
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (test:root/Microsoft/...rResourceRecord) [Add-DnsServerResourceRecord], Cim

Comment: I can't get it to work with NAPTR either. Here's my notes: https://www.yesthatblog.com/post/0093-naptr-powershell/#update-2020-12-30

Comment: A related question (deleting NAPTR records) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65523375/how-to-use-powershell-to-delete-a-single-naptr-record and may provide some clues about how to add the records.